# Mod only tags on the main site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, specific-tag, weekly-topic-challenge

Can we get a mod only tag for the main site called [weekly-challenge-winner](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weekly-challenge-winner)? Is this feasable? Desirable?
Discuss!

Comment: [Isaac Moses's answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/783) is IMO clearly correct according to Stack Exchange culture, to the extent that I'm going to go ahead and tag this [meta-tag:status-declined]. (That relates to the [meta-tag:feature-request] part of this question. Of course people should feel free to continue [meta-tag:discussion] on desirability of a [tag:weekly-challenge-winner] tag: but be aware that such discussion will be largely (or wholly) moot.)

Answer (score 4):

"Meta-tags," which describe some characteristic of the question other than its content are [explicitly discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on SE. I think that the method that msh210 chose for labeling the winner, a [bolded comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13922/bootstrapping-problem-havdalah-ends-shabbat-for-one-who-didnt-daven-maariv#comment25409_13922) with a link back to the challenge, is both more appropriate and more informative.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with [Isaac](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/783/472).  msh210 also linked to the winning entry from the challenge post, which hits all the touch-points.  Since winners are not determined by some objective standard but rather, essentially, on a curve, I don't think the set of all challenge-winning questions is likely to be that interesting to people browsing the site.  (A winner in a light week could be "not as good" as the second-place question in a bountiful week.)